# How to get length of object in controller from service function

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array

The inner console returns the value of length but the external console is returning undefined value. Please let me know where I am lacking. 
listFetch is a service.

```js
.controller('list', function($scope,$routeParams,listFetch){
        $scope.listCurrent={};
        $scope.id=$routeParams.id;
        var listNumber,len;
        listNumber='list'+$scope.id;
        listFetch.getList().success(function(data) {
            $scope.listCurrent = data[listNumber];
            console.log($scope.listCurrent.length);
        });
        len=$scope.listCurrent.length;
        console.log(len);

});
```

`

Comment: Verify first that $scope.listCurrent actually has any data inside it. Try logging it first and check if you have something there.

Comment: yes @RusPaul its working thats why I am able to get the value from `console.log($scope.listCurrent.length);` withing the function

Comment: You are asynchronously getting your list, so when the len=$scope.listCurrent.length is being set $scope.listCurrent doesn't exist so it's undefined.

Comment: @jme11 How can I retrieve it then?

Comment: A watch like in the answer provided below is one option.  Another is that you can use the resolve in ngRoute to make sure that the data is already there when the view is loaded.  Here's a [tutorial](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) for using resolve.

Answer (score 1):

`listFetch.getList()` is an asynchronous function which means that it gives you result only after a moment. But you ask for it (in the "external" console log) right away.

You could do sth like this:

```
$scope.$watch('listCurrent', function () {
    len=$scope.listCurrent.length
    console.log(len);
}
```

**Small gotcha:** `$scope.$watch` will also run at the beginning of the controller initialisation, when the `$scope.listCurrent` is in fact `undefined`. To take it under consideration, you may do this:

```
$scope.$watch('listCurrent', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        len=$scope.listCurrent.length
        console.log(len);
    }
}
```

(on the first watch both old and new values are undefined, it won't happen later ;) )

Comment: Why console.log is returning the value twice in this case.

Comment: Did you remove it from the `success()` callback?

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery with angularJS and then I make this inside the controller to call the service:

```
listFetch.getList().success(function(response){
    $scope.sliders = response.data;
 });

console.log($($scope.sliders).length);
```

Returns the length of the array.

To use this declare in the index.html the jquery before angularjs.

I hope this helps.